# Trying to send specific SPL Token but creates new token instead

Tags: transactions, spl-token, spl-token-program, spl, spl-associated-token-account

I'm trying to send a SPL Token but when I execute the code below it creates an unknown token and sends it, It does not recognize the token address / programID. Where should I pass the token address?

```
    const mint = await createMint(
      connection,
      fromAddress.addressKeypair,
      fromAddress.addressKeypair.publicKey,
      null,
      9,
      undefined,
      {},
      "7i5KKsX2weiTkry7jA4ZwSuXGhs5eJBEjY8vVxR4pfRx".TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    );
    console.log(mint);
    // Get the token account of the fromWallet address, and if it does not exist, create it
    const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      fromAddress.addressKeypair,
      mint,
      fromAddress.addressKeypair.publicKey,
      "7i5KKsX2weiTkry7jA4ZwSuXGhs5eJBEjY8vVxR4pfRx".TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID

    );

    // Get the token account of the toWallet address, and if it does not exist, create it
    const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      fromAddress.addressKeypair,
      mint,
      toaddress,
      "7i5KKsX2weiTkry7jA4ZwSuXGhs5eJBEjY8vVxR4pfRx".TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID

    );

    // Mint 1 new token to the "fromTokenAccount" account we just created
    let signature = await mintTo(
      connection,
      fromAddress.addressKeypair,
      mint,
      fromTokenAccount.address,
      fromAddress.addressKeypair.publicKey,
      1000000000,
      undefined,
      {},
      "7i5KKsX2weiTkry7jA4ZwSuXGhs5eJBEjY8vVxR4pfRx".TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    );
    console.log("mint tx:", signature);

    // Transfer the new token to the "toTokenAccount" we just created
    signature = await transfer(
      connection,
      fromAddress.addressKeypair,
      fromTokenAccount.address,
      toTokenAccount.address,
      fromAddress.addressKeypair.publicKey,
      amount,
      undefined,
      {},
      "7i5KKsX2weiTkry7jA4ZwSuXGhs5eJBEjY8vVxR4pfRx".TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    ); 
    console.log("sig: ", signature);

    response["result"] = 1;
    response["data"] = { txid: signature };
    response["error"] = null;
    return console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    response["result"] = 0;
    response["data"] = { txid: null };
    response["error"] = error;
    return console.log(response);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have copied this code from an example.

You don't need `createMint` and `mintTo` parts because you already have the token and you possess enough amount of token to transfer (I assume).

replace `mint` variable with the address of the token you would like to transfer.

```
const mint = new PublicKey("<address of your token>");

// Get the token account of the fromWallet address, and if it does not exist, create it
const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  fromAddress.addressKeypair,
  mint,
  fromAddress.addressKeypair.publicKey,
  "7i5KKsX2weiTkry7jA4ZwSuXGhs5eJBEjY8vVxR4pfRx".TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID

);

// Get the token account of the toWallet address, and if it does not exist, create it
const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  fromAddress.addressKeypair,
  mint,
  toaddress,
  "7i5KKsX2weiTkry7jA4ZwSuXGhs5eJBEjY8vVxR4pfRx".TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID

);

// Transfer the token to the "toTokenAccount" we just created
signature = await transfer(
  connection,
  fromAddress.addressKeypair,
  fromTokenAccount.address,
  toTokenAccount.address,
  fromAddress.addressKeypair.publicKey,
  amount,
  undefined,
  {},
  "7i5KKsX2weiTkry7jA4ZwSuXGhs5eJBEjY8vVxR4pfRx".TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
); 
console.log("sig: ", signature);

response["result"] = 1;
response["data"] = { txid: signature };
response["error"] = null;
return console.log(response);
} catch (error) {
response["result"] = 0;
response["data"] = { txid: null };
response["error"] = error;
return console.log(response);
}
```